# Invalid Swift Support - The files aren’t at the expected location

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload my app, developed using **Xamarin** (Visual Studio for Mac 7.5.2, XCode 9.2) and i'm using this script https://github.com/bq/ipa-packager to deal with the SwiftSupport issue.

However, when I create the new IPA file and upload to the appstore connect I got the following error:

> Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftDarwin.dylib,
>   libswiftDispatch.dylib, libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib,
>   libswiftUIKit.dylib, libswiftContacts.dylib, libswiftCore.dylib,
>   libswiftFoundation.dylib, libswiftObjectiveC.dylib,
>   libswiftCoreImage.dylib aren’t at the expected location
>   /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks. Move the file to the expected location,
>   rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and
>   resubmit it.

We are out of options, does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Have no exp. with Xamarin. But is this the only way to generate iPA? `Xcode`'s `Product->Archive` does not work for `Xamarin`?

Comment: One: What is the structure of your app bundle. Two: Are you using an Xcode GM release and the swift libraries from it? Three: Use Xcode to produce an a Swift-based iOS project, archive it and publish an adhoc ipa and review the resulting bundle. Does it match the structure of yours? Are the Swift libraries the correct version?